# The keys of a dictionary are not in the order when they are added?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
>>> d={}
>>> d['c']=3
>>> d['b']=2
>>> d['a']=1
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> d.keys()
['a', 'c', 'b']
```

Are the keys in a dictionary not ordered in the same order they are added into the dictionary?
What order are they in?

What shall I do if I want to have the keys of a dictionary in the order that they are added into the dictionary?

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 5):

`dict` is an unordered data structure. Keys will come out in some order when you iterate over them, but this may bear little resemblance to the order in which they were added. In return, you get `O(1)` lookup.

Use `collections.OrderedDict` if you need to retain the order.

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionaries don't preserve order, and you cannot count on **any** particular order. Dictionary is a store for values where, by design, values are to be referred to by their keys – and not by a particular "slot" in which they are.

If you need to preserve order of added elements, use lists where a "slot" is referred to by an index, e.g. myList[3]. If you need to have 2 values coupled together (corresponding a "key" and a "value" as in your example), use a list of tuples.

Comment: You can use `collections.OrderedDict`